# Pandas 0.20.3 "KeyError: '[1 2] not in index'" When Trying to Select Columns to Display in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm working through the book **Mastering Pandas for Finance** and I created the following DataFrame for the S&P 500:

```
    sp500 = pd.read_csv("sp500.csv", index='Symbol', usecols=[0, 2, 3, 7])
```

Returns the following DataFrame:

[S&P 500 DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQPSB.png)

A part of the exercise is to then display the dataframe with only select columns using the following code:

```
            $ sp500[[1, 2]].head(3)
```

Which should produce the following DataFrame:

[S&P 500 DataFrame with Indexed Columns Only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UIiy.png)

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
    KeyError: '[1 2] not in index'
```

**Traceback**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-9993ec8d3122> in <module>()
----> 1 sp500[[1, 2]].head(3)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1956         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   1957             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 1958             return self._getitem_array(key)
   1959         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   1960             return self._getitem_frame(key)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2000             return self.take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
   2001         else:
-> 2002             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2003             return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
   2004 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1229                 mask = check == -1
   1230                 if mask.any():
-> 1231                     raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
   1232 
   1233                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: '[1 2] not in index'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the image it looks like the names of the columns of `sp500` are `sector`, `price` and `book value`. So pandas is complaining because you are asking columns that are called `1` and `2`.

`sp500[sp500.columns[[1,2]]]` will give you the 2nd and third columns which I think is what you are after.